# My compiled C++ program is too small. How can I make it larger?

Tags: c++

I have a C++ program that compiles to 9.5k. I would like it to be over 1MB. I did the following to pad it up to about 18k, but doing this all the way to 1MB would be hard.

The code is unreachable, but due to compiler optimizations I had to make it appear reachable, hence the bool changes.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    bool a = false;
    cout << endl << "Passed parameters";
    for (int i = 0 ; i < argc ; i++)
    {
        if(i == 0)
        {
            cout << endl << "Run Path (Arg0): " << argv[i];
            a=true;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << endl << "Arg" << i << ": " << argv[i];
            if(a){a=false;}
        }
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
    system("pause");
    if (a){
    string pad1 = "padpadpadpadpadpadpadpadpadpadpadpadpadpadp1adpadpadpadpadpa";
    string pad2 = "dapdapdapdapdapdapdapdapd2apdapdapdapdapdapdapdapdapdapdapd";
    string pad3 = "dipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipd3ipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdip";
    string pad4 = "dipdipdipdi4pdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdip";
    string pad5 = "dipdipdipd5ipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdip";
    string pad6 = "dipdipdipd6ipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdip";
    string pad7 = "dipdipdipd7i1pdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdip";
    string pad8 = "dipdipdip8dipdipdip1dipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdip";
    string pad9 = "dipdipdipd9ipdipdipdipdip1dipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdip";
    string pad10= "padpadpadpadpadpadpadpadpadpadp1adpadpadpadp1adpadpadpadpadpa";
    string pad11= "dapdapdapdapdapdapdapdapd2apdapdapdapdapdap1dapdapdapdapdapd";
    string pad12= "dipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipd3ipdipdipdipdipdipdip1dipdip";
    string pad13= "dipdipdipdi4pdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdi1pdipdip";
    string pad14= "dipdipdipd5ipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipd2ipdipdi1pdipdipdipdip";
    string pad15= "dipdipdipd6ipdipdipdip2dipdipdipdipdipdipdip1dipdipdipdipdip";
    string pad16= "dipdipdipd7ipdipdipdip2dipdipdipdipdip1dipdipdipdipdipdipdip";
    string pad17= "dipdipdip8dipdipdipdipdipdipd2ipdip1dipdipdipdipdipdipdipdip";
    string pad18= "dipdipdipd9ipdipdipdip1dipdipdipdipdipdi2pdipdipdipdipdipdip";
    string pad19= "padpadpadpadpadpadpadpadpadpadpad2padpadpadp1adpadpadpadpadpa";
    string pad20= "dapdapdapdapdapd2apdapdapd2apdapdapdapdapdapdapdapdapdapdapd";
    string pad21= "dipdipdipdipdipd2ipdipdi2pdipdipd3ipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdip";
    string pad22= "dipdipdipdi4pdipdipdipd2ipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdip";
    string pad23= "dipdipdipd5ipdip2dipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdip";
    string pad24= "dipdipdipd6ipdipdipdi2pdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdip";
    string pad25= "dipdipdipd7i1pdipdipdipdipdipdip2dipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdip";
    string pad26= "dipdipdip8dipdipdip1dipdipdip1dipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdip";
    string pad27= "dipdipdipd9ipdipdipd1ipdip1dipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdip";
    string pad28= "padpadpadpadpadpadpadpadp1adpadp1adpadpadpadp1adpadpadpadpadpa";
    string pad29= "dapdapdapdapdapdapdapdapd2apdapdapdapdapda1p1dapdapdapdapdapd";
    string pad30= "dipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipd3ipdipd1ipdipdipdipdip1dipdip";
    string pad31= "dipdipdipdi4pdipdipdipdipdipdipdi1pdipdipdipdipdipdi1pdipdip";
    string pad32= "dipdipdipd5ipdipdipdi1pdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdi1pdipdipdipdip";
    string pad33= "dipdipdipd6ipdipdipdip1dipdipdipdipdipdipdip1dipdipdipdipdip";
    string pad34= "dipdipdipd7ipdipdipdipdip1dipdipdipdip1dipdipdipdipdipdipdip";
    string pad35= "dipdipdip8dipdipdipdipdipdipdi1pdip1dipdipdipdipdipdipdipdip";
    string pad36= "dipdipdipd9ipdipdipdip1dipdipdipd1ipdipdipdipdipdipdipdipdip";}
    return;
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Normally it's the other way around!

Comment: Well the compiler might optimize away/remove all the pad strings, since you dont use them.

Comment: I always tend to have the same problem myself (ironic).

Comment: you must work for microsoft!

Comment: @Anthales - it is being used to test a system that disregards small files.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why on earth would you want your compiled program to be larger. Furthermore you got a program using `<iostream>` to compile down to `9.5k` without actively trying to make it as small as possible?

Comment: I will gladly trade my large files for your small files :)

Comment: @Muggen That is why I have the bool toggle and the code in an if statement. That was enough to trick the compiler into including the padding code.

Comment: What happens if you force link in a bunch of large libraries? What I'm suggesting is to tweak the link phase.

Comment: Just edit the file and add junk at the end, windows doesn't care

Comment: Checks calendar... nope. That was more than two weeks ago.

Comment: Link in some large libraries like boost or wxWidgets. Particulary debug versions of them. (Make sure you actually use some classes/functions from them in the code, otherwise the linker will discard them). I have been very successful at keeping my executables upwards of 40 MB in size with this strategy.

Comment: Wait a minute system("pause") that's windows shell. What compiler does 9.5k to a c++ app? Is it a COM file?

Comment: So this is just being used to spew out the arguments being given to it by another application. I know system shell calls are bad, and I don't really care in this case. But yes, if you take out all the padding code, it compiles to 9.5k.

Comment: Just include a boost header. That should successfully increase your executable size by approximately 23459834x.

Comment: Mostly out of curiosity, what kind of system ignores small files?

Comment: Interesting how many upvotes this question gets considering how common such a problem is (that is to say not at all)

Comment: I love the way he tried to padapadapada by hand.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
char waste[1024*1024] = {1};
```

At least on my TDM-GCC (on Win7), the output is 1 MB bigger; if you write

```
char waste[1024*1024] = {0};
```

it'll be optimized out (resulting in 27kB).

Comment: This gets optimized out as well using VS10.

Comment: Any particular reason you need to have optimizations turned on?

Comment: @Dustin Well, if it gets optimized, you still could write out your initializer list - you could write a program for that ;)

Comment: @Dustin And/Or try to actually access the array members (maybe assign to all of them in a loop in your `main` or so).

Comment: Still trying to figure out how to stop optimization of this. I have disabled every single project preference for optimization, I have used the /MT switch (which got me up to 137kb) but this is still not allocating space in the binary.

Comment: Another way I just thought of may be adding a large resource file - or did you get it to work, since you accepted my answer already?

Comment: @Dustin: Allocate the big array, fill it in a loop and print it, but don't make that branch of the code actually execute at runtime. Maybe with a `volatile bool exec_wastefill = false`.

Comment: Use a XPM format to save your avatar :-) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_PixMap

Answer (score 8):

Compile with a static executable  (`-static` flag for `gcc`) and add system includes till you get over 1MB.  I think you can do the same with Windows but I don't program in Windows so I could be wrong, but here's a link that seem to describe how: http://www.geekadmin.com/?p=34

Comment: If I'm not mistaken (been some time) you can compile statically against the C++ std library using `/MT`

Comment: This really is a better answer than Anthales, no offense to Anthales

Answer (score 4):

There is a simple solution:
You could just append some data file to your .exe file. Windows complains that the publisher is unknown, but executes the program without problem after confirmation.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could create a file that is 1MB in size and read all of the information into some variable or data structure.

Either that or you could create some data structure and in a loop, write a bunch of junk into it. Note that this will probably make your program significantly slower.

Comment: I think he is talking about the binary it self, not the memory the program occupies on runtime.

Comment: I am pretty sure neither of those things would actually affect the compiled EXE, only the memory/cpu use when running.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/12687/

Answer (score 2):

```
int main(){}
char lol[1024*1024] = { 1 };
```

note that char `lol[1024*1024];` is not enough, as otherwise the compiler just tells the OS to create a zero-filled area. This way, a 1MB heap of senseless ones is embed in the program.

Comment: Not ones, but one and many zeros.

Comment: No. If you give only one element in the initialization, it'll be copied all over the entire array.

Comment: I stripped out all of the padding code in the sample above and added this. It now compiles to 9.12k :(

Comment: It must be then the VC++ compiler that optimizes it for you. I'm sorry then.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's completely wrong. The remaining elements will be initialized to zero.

Comment: No, the elements that don't appear in the initializer are zero initialized. "If there are fewer initializer-clauses in the list than there are members in the aggregate, then each member not explicitly initialized shall be initialized from an empty initializer list" _-- n3337 8.5.1 [dcl.init.aggr] /7_

Comment: Checked by experiment on GCC 4.7.0. One and many zeros :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make the executable foot-print large by statically allocating memory at compile-time.  For instance, simply add:

```
static char padding[1024 * 1024] = {1};
```

That will statically allocate the storage rather than cause it to be allocated at run-time, which is what would occur if you left out the initialization value for the first memory slot in the array.  In other words without the explicit compile-time initialization to a non-zero value, the array is stored in the `.bss` section of the object file, and thus the linker only stores a tab to indicate to the OS runtime it needs to allocate the memory for the array at execution time, rather than allocating the memory statically in the `.data` section of the object file, which will in-turn create a memory footprint for the array in the executable itself.